# How to enable the access to Azure services in my AZURE SQL database server?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to create a "Integration Runtime" (AZURE-SSIS type) in my data factory. (To run my SSIS packages in cloud) I already have a virtual machine (Azure SQL data base server Up and running).

While during the IR creation process I'm not able to link my AZURE SQL database SSISDB catalog to "Catalog database server endpoint"  (OR) the server is not showing up in the drop down box.

In the MSDN blog it says

```
"Confirm that the **Allow access to Azure services** setting is enabled for the database server. This is not applicable when you use Azure SQL Database with virtual network service endpoints/Managed Instance to host SSISDB."
```

Could anyone know how to enable this feature ? I hope by enabling this feature I can link my server in the IR and run the packages in the cloud.

Thanks

Comment: The 1st result from googling "azure sql database allow access to azure services" explains how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To allow applications from Azure to connect to your Azure SQL server,
>   Azure connections must be enabled. When an application from Azure
>   attempts to connect to your database server, the firewall verifies
>   that Azure connections are allowed. A firewall setting with starting
>   and ending address equal to 0.0.0.0 indicates Azure connections are
>   allowed. If the connection attempt is not allowed, the request does
>   not reach the Azure SQL Database server.

you can do it any way, powershell, az cli, arm templates. if you go to the portal to the firewall blade, there would be a button to do that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look where is located on below image.

[image]

On [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule#create-a-server-level-ip-firewall-rule) documentation you will have instructions how to reach that screen.